# How to run K-means on value_counts of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to use Kmeans to cluster a dataframe with a prepared dataset by the count of values.
Then I want to plot this.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
frq = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(presult["ClientIP"].value_counts().to_dict(), orient="index").reset_index()
frq.columns = ['IP', 'Frq']
print(frq.columns)
print(frq)
Index(['IP', 'Frq'], dtype='object')
                                         IP   Frq
0                             2X.1XX.X.X  1158
1    X:598:X:db8a:X:X:e9aa   408
2                             18.X.X.109   405
3                              217.X.X.28   394
4                            92.X.X.119   360
..                                      ...   ...
760                          216.10.X.X     1
761                          185.152.X.X     1
```

From the prepped dataset I assume I can call:

```
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 1).fit(frq)
```

This does not work because my IP column is a string. However, I need to know which IP goes into which cluster.

I'd add a column per IP to see to which cluster it belongs to:

```
frq['kmean'] = kmeans_model.labels_
print(frq['kmean'].value_counts())
```

Would anyone know how to convince `sklearn` to cluster based on the value count within a dataframe?

Comment: `kmeans_model.fit_transform(frq['Frq'])`

Comment: Sadly that results into other problems with the array being 1-dimensional.

Comment: How can you cluster data with one feature???? I don't get your approach. When you want to cluster it with the frequence only, it does not make any sense..

Comment: You are right. While you can use 1d data for clustering sklearn focuses on (better suited) use cases for multi-variant clustering (only).